# Mean value property (average over spheres) implies smooth without continuity assumption?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I know that if $u$ is continuous an has the mean value property for all spheres in an open domain $U$, then $u \in C^\infty(U)$ and is in fact harmonic, and hence analytic in $U$. If I know that $u$ is borel measurable, bounded, and satisfies the mean value property for all spheres in a domain $U$, can I conclude that $u$ is continuous in $U$, and hence $C^\infty(U)$?

Comment: You can find a example here https://books.google.nl/books?id=6XbrCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Classical and Modern Potential Theory and Applications
 edited by K. GowriSankaran, J. Bliedtner, D. Feyel, M. Goldstein, W.K. Hayman, I. Netuka , page 368

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function Says all that is needed is locally integrable

Comment: @Deliasaghi, the book you mention seems to find a counterexample for when one only assumes the MVP holds for spheres of a single radius.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You assume 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{r^{n-1}\alpha_n}\int_{\partial B_r (x)} f(t)\, dt
$$
for all $x$. This implies 
$$
\int_{B_r (x)} f(t)\,dt = \int_0^r \int_{\partial B_s (x)} f(t)\, dt \,ds = f(x) \int_0^r \alpha_n s^{n-1}\, ds = \alpha_n / n \cdot f(x).
$$
But the left-hand of this equation is just the convolution
$$
(f \ast 1_{B_r (0)})(x).
$$
It is not hard to see that the convolution of an $L^\infty$ and an $L^1$ function is continuous. Hence so is $f$.